# Index of dataframe different from list that was passed as argument

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe with index provided from a list.
Given the list:

```
all_values_eixo_x_cdf[:10]

array([0.   , 0.017, 0.033, 0.05 , 0.067, 0.083, 0.1  , 0.117, 0.133,
   0.15 ])
```

So what I do is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=all_values_eixo_x_cdf[:10])
```

But some indexes are different as you can see below:

```
df.index
Float64Index([0.0, 0.017, 0.033, 0.05, 0.067, 0.083, 0.1, 0.11699999999999999,
          0.133, 0.15],
         dtype='float64')
```

I have no ideia why though. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is certainly just a machine precision issue. Not all number can be stored exactly as you intend using float format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could index the dataframe taking the first `n` digits of the elements in the array using [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({}, index=all_values_eixo_x_cdf[:10].round(n))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I have no idea why it was not working because all values in my list had only 3 decimal values.